# Binary search on List<Tuple<int,int>> in c#

Tags: c#, list, search

I use C# language and I have a little question about `List<Tuple<int,int>>`. Assume that I created a `List<Tuple<int,int>>` and then inserted some entry to it like: `(12,3),(154,43),(85,342)`

Now I want to search the `List` JUST by first item, i.e. just by `item1` and I want to do this by binary search.

something like this:

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> tt = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
tt.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(12,32));
tt.sort();
tt.binarysearch(item1:12);
```

and some output like this:

`12 32`

Now is there any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, BinarySearch takes IComparer, and you can create your own custom comparer that inherits from `IComparer<Tuple<int, int>>`

As such:

```
public class BinarySearchComparer : IComparer<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<int, int> f1, Tuple<int, int> f2)
    {
        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(f1.Item1, f2.Item1);
    }
}
```

and example:

```
tt.Binarysearch(12, new BinarySearchComparer());
```

See more for information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey Erti-Chris! Thanks a lot, you did it!

Comment: Yes, it should work. I did edit it a little before, maybe you have not refreshed?

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `BinarySearch` has no argument named `item1`.

Comment: don't think you need item1, removed it.